# React при обработке события перезатирается state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

В родительском компоненте есть инициализация state

```
state = { 
  tasks: {},
  users: {
    userId: 1,
    userName: "Artem Gavrilov",    
  },
  appData: {
    selectedDate: new Date(),
    unfinished: {},
  }, 
};
```

Есть дочерний компонент с формой из текстовых инпутов.

```js
export default class Form extends React.Component {
  handleTextChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    this.setState({...this.state, appData: {
      unfinished: {
        [name]: value,
        }
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="task-container">
        <form className="task-form">
          <div className="task-line">
            <p className="task-p">Название задачи</p>
            <input onChange={this.handleTextChange} className="task-input" type="text" required name="taskName"/>
          </div>
          <div className="task-line">
            <p className="task-p">Описание задачи</p>
            <textarea onChange={this.handleTextChange} className="task-textarea" cols="20" rows="5" type="text" required name="taskDesc"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Я хочу заполнять объект state.appData.unfinished текущими значениями из инпутов.
Проблема в том, что при вводе символов во втором поле - state перезатирается и я теряю значение из первого (и наоборот). Если я записываю в state.[name], все работает корректно, но мне хочется работать с такой структурой состояния.
Как перестать перезатирать состояние во вложенном объекте?

Comment: `this.setState({...this.state, appData: {}` это не так работает,`...this.state` не нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе идея в правильном направлении, но есть небольшой нюанс, вот пример с сохранением `state` без его перезаписывания:

```js
class Form extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    // засетим значение по-умолчанию, хотя бы пустой объект
    this.state = {
      appData: {
        unfinished: {},
      },
    }; 
  }

  handleTextChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    // сохранение значения в объекте стейта
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      appData: {
        unfinished: {
          ...prevState.appData.unfinished, // объединяем предыдущее значение с новым значением (копируем объект)
          [name]: value, // перезапишем проперти `[name]` в копии объекта `prevState.appData.unfinished`)
        }
      }
    }));
  }
  
  showStateToConsole = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="task-container">
        <form className="task-form">
          <div className="task-line">
            <p className="task-p">Название задачи</p>
            <input
              onChange={this.handleTextChange}
              className="task-input"
              type="text"
              required
              name="taskName"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="task-line">
            <p className="task-p">Описание задачи</p>
            <textarea
              onChange={this.handleTextChange}
              className="task-textarea"
              cols="20"
              rows="5"
              type="text"
              required
              name="taskDesc"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.showStateToConsole}>Show state in console...</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Есть очень хороший пример с массой примеров на enSO: [Updating an object with setState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43639228/5275890)